# Subtype / SuperType Relationships: How to fulfill these requirements

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema, database-design

I am fighting with myself trying to model a DB to fulfill certain requirements.

- There are two main entities.  One is known as Team, think of a business or organization.  The other will be an individual.
- Teams can also be made of individuals (TeamContacts)
- This is a member required site (i.e. must become a Member and log into the site to do anything)
- TeamContacts will only be an internal directory and they will not have access to the site unless of course they are a Member and then will have such privileges.
- Individuals classified as TeamContacts may or may not be Members of the site.  This is my major concern here.  **It will be very difficult, at times impossible, to worry if a TeamContact is also a Member and vice versa.**  Memberships can lapse and TeamContacts may go from team to team.  History for Members will be maintained but history to track the possible movement of TeamContacts between Teams will not.
- The only attributes that would be shared exclusively between a Member and a TeamContact (baring the attributes that exist at the Party level) is FirstName and LastName.

Here are four possibilities that I have come up with.  As I said I don't really know in what direction I should go.  It might be that none of my options are ideal.  I would appreciate any feedback that can help sort this out.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You said, "Teams can also be made of individuals." If a team can *also* be made of individuals, what *else* can a team be made of?

Comment: @Catcall The easiest way to think of it is a Business (Team) and an employee (TeamContact).  In that sense a Business is definitely not an individual (Member or TeamContact).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly. Can a team contact be anything besides a person?

Comment: @Catcall A TeamContact can only be a person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, it looks like Ex1 is the only diagram that expresses these two requirements.

- Every team contact is a person.
- Some persons are members.

Ex2 doesn't refer to members at all.

Ex3 would seem to allow any party (including teams) as a team contact.

Ex4 explicitly allows any party (including teams) to be a team contact.

You might consider another unexpressed but common requirement--that a person can be a contact of only one team at a time. (That might not apply in your particular case. I can't tell.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I originally used a variation of Ex1, the difference being I listed the Person SubTypes as Exclusive.  That is what got me questioning things.  I changed to Inclusive though to allow the possibility of a Person being a TeamContact and Member.  I just wanted to make sure to not enforce that a TeamContact has to be a Member first, does this model allow this flexibility?  I understand there will be dups though but don't know how to get around it.

Comment: Although I did not list a contact belonging to only one team doesn't the model cover that as there is not a M:M between Team::TeamContact?

Comment: Ex1 doesn't require a person to be a member before they can be a team contact. And, duh, it doesn't allow a person to be a team contact for more than one team at a time. (I can only plead insufficient caffeine.)

Comment: caffeine or not you are a great source of info on this site and I appreciate it.  I was hoping you would see this question.  Thanks.